# How to use Gulp to regex search with match groups the contents of a file?

Tags: gulp

I am trying to create a Gulp version 4 task that

- Reads the contents of a given file
- Uses regex to find the string: `Public ReadOnly isHealthy As Boolean = (True|False)`
- Return the value matched in the first match group, True or False.

I have looked at [gulp-text-simple](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-text-simple) and [gulp-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-scan) (which is no longer maintained and uses depreciated [gulp-util](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-util))

I haven't been able to find any examples showing how to do what I am looking for.

Comment: You want to return true or false?  Do you just want a list of filenames and true/false Are you going to do something differently with the trues vs. the falses?

Comment: @Mark I want to parse the current value of the isHealthy variable located in a single known file.  The value will be true or false and I need to open the file and run a regex match on each line looking for the line that matches the regex expression /Public ReadOnly isHealthy As Boolean = (True|False)/ and when that line is found (it will be, it's always in there) return the True or False value that the first match group matched on, the (True|False) part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two approaches (I recommend the second one but it depends on what you will doing with the results like do you want to run a gulp plugin on the Trues and/or Falses).

---

Approach 1:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const gulpif = require("gulp-if");
const path = require("path");
const noop = require("gulp-noop");

const regex = /Public ReadOnly isHealthy As Boolean = (True|False)/;

// console.log("Public ReadOnly isHealthy As Boolean = True".match(regex));  // s/b true
// console.log("Public ReadOnly isHealthy As Boolean = False".match(regex)); // s/b false

const condition = function (file) {

  // here file is a vinyl file
  const match = file.contents.toString().match(regex);      
  console.log(`${path.basename(file.path)}: ` + match[1]);

  return match[1] === "True";
}

const ifRegEx = function() {

  return gulp.src('./src/*.txt')

    .pipe(gulpif(condition, noop(), noop()));
    // .pipe(gulpif(condition, gulp.dest('./truePile'), gulp.dest('./falsePile')));
};

exports.ifRegEx = ifRegEx;
```

With `gulpif` you can handle the `True`'s differently from the `False`'s - in the commented code they are copied to different folders.

---

Approach 2:

```
const glob = require("glob");
const files = glob.sync('./src/*.txt');  // returns an array
const fs = require("fs");

const findRegEx = function (done) {

  const regex = /Public ReadOnly isHealthy As Boolean = (True|False)/;

  files.forEach( file => {
    let contents = fs.readFileSync(file, "UTF8");
    const match = contents.match(regex);
    console.log(`${file}: ` + match[1]);

    // if match[1] === "True" doThis;
    // else doThat;
  });
  done();
}

exports.findRegEx = findRegEx;
```

This will print out the filename and True/False like:

```
./src/testFalse.txt: False
./src/testTrue.txt: True
./src/testTrue2.txt: True
```